# Can Facebook CPA ads be optimized based on pixel fires?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

When ad type is set to "CPA", is it possible to use "offsite_conversion" with pixels, as we can do with "oCPM" ads?

For example, why can't I use the following:

```
           $fbRequest['bid_info'] = array('ACTIONS' => $cData['creative_max_bid'] * 100);
           $fbRequest['bid_type'] = 'CPA';
           $fbRequest['conversion_specs'] = array('action.type' => array('offsite_conversion'), 'offsite_pixel' => $pixelRemoteId);
```

This kind of syntax works perfectly for oCPM ads but I wanted to try using CPA ads instead.

Instead, when I try to post the above to FB API, I get an exception with instructions to use "link_click" action instead.

Thank you,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CPA documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/cost-per-action-ads/), no, CPA ads can't be used with offsite conversion pixels, only the actions listed in the documentation can be bid as CPA

Page Likes, Offer Claims, Offsite Link Clicks, Mobile App Installs

Comment: Thank you! Are there any indications that this will come as an option in future? I actually read the documentation *blush*, but was wondering if anything changed because sometimes documentation is behind the development... (which is also why I tried to use above code snippet :) )